# Tags not being deleted in Microsoft Office Object model

Tags: interop, vsto, powerpoint, object-model

I have this weird problem with the Powerpoint office model. For various reasons I store some user data in the tags of the presentation. But I need to be able to strip them out. The delete just fine in the object model, but when I save the presentation, the tags are restored. Here is a sample program:

```
// Reference to Microsoft.Office.Core and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint
// required to execute this code.
using System;
using Ppt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace PptCleaner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filename = args[0];
            var app = new Ppt.Application();
            var pres = app.Presentations.Open(filename);
            // Presentation has four tags, so pres.Tags.Count == 4
            while(pres.Tags.Count > 0)
                pres.Tags.Delete(pres.Tags.Name(1));
            // After loop pres.Tags.Count == 0
            pres.Save();
            // After save pres.Tags.Count has gone back to 4
            pres.Close();
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this with a nearly identical program (the only difference is that I hardcoded the filename and printed the counts to the console).

Comment: Alex, would you mind posting your code? If you put it in an answer I'll accept it, since it is crickets on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per OP's request this is the code with which I was unable to reproduce the issue:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application ppt = new Application();
            Presentation pres = ppt.Presentations.Open(@"C:\test2.pptm");
            Console.WriteLine("count before: " + pres.Tags.Count);
            while (pres.Tags.Count > 0) pres.Tags.Delete(pres.Tags.Name(1));
            Console.WriteLine("count after: " + pres.Tags.Count);
            pres.Save();
            pres.Close();
            ppt.Quit();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I had previously added four tags to `test2.pptm` via a macro in the workbook. The first time I ran this program I got the output 0 followed by 4, the second time I got 0 both times (as expected).